# How can I update data to my PostgreSQL database using a form in PHP?

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I am trying to update some data to Postgres using a PHP form, but I keep receiving this error message:

> Error with DB. Details: PDOException: SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7
>   ERROR: syntax error at end of input LINE 1: ...te = '04/04/2020',
>   check_out_date = '04/05/2020' WHERE id = ^ in
>   /app/web/week05/update.php:13 Stack trace: #0
>   /app/web/week05/update.php(13): PDOStatement->execute() #1 {main}

This is how my php form looks like:

```
    <?php echo "   <form method='post' action='update.php'>

    <div class='form-group'>
        <label for='reservationID'>Reservation ID:</label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='reservationID' name='reservationID' value='$reservation_id' disabled>
        <div class='valid-feedback'>Valid.</div>
      </div>

      <div class='form-group'>
        <label for='RoomNumber'>Room Number: </label>
        <input type='text' class='form-control' id='RoomNumber' name='RoomNumber' value='$room_number' required>
        <div class='valid-feedback'>Valid.</div>
      </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        Check-In Date: <input width='276' id='checkInDate' name='checkInDate' required />
        Check-Out Date: <input width='276' id='checkOutDate' name='checkOutDate' required />

    </div>

    <button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'>Update</button>
    <br>
    <br>
    </form>
  </div>";

  ?>
```

And here's the code of my update.php file:

```
    <?php
$id = $_POST['reservationID'];
$RoomNumber = $_POST['RoomNumber'];
$checkInDate = $_POST['checkInDate'];
$checkOutDate = $_POST['checkOutDate'];

require "connection.php";
$db = get_db();

try
{
    $update = $db->prepare("UPDATE reservation SET room_number = '$RoomNumber', check_in_date = '$checkInDate', check_out_date = '$checkOutDate' WHERE id = $id");
    $update->execute();
}
catch (Exception $ex)
{
    echo "Error with DB. Details: $ex";
    die();
}
header("Location: search3.php");

die(); 

?>
```

Really needed help here, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Disabled fields are **not passed** to server. Use `input type=hidden` instead:

```
<input type='hidden' id='reservationID' name='reservationID' value='$reservation_id'>
```

Also, **correct usage** of prepared statements in your case is:

```
$update = $db->prepare("UPDATE reservation SET room_number = ?, check_in_date = ?, check_out_date = ? WHERE id = ?");
$update->execute([
    $RoomNumber,
    $checkInDate,
    $checkOutDate,
    $id,
]);
```

Comment: Alternative solution to using `type='hidden'`: If he wants to actually *show* the reservation id, he could also use `readonly="readonly"` instead of `disabled`.